# Keeping track of time in java Tamagotchi game

Tags: java

I'm trying to recreate a simple version of the [tamagotchi game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamagotchi) in Java. As the pet ages, it will hatch / grow old etc. in real time, and I'm wondering what's the best way to keep track of the time?

I have considered using threads combined with `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `LocalTime.now()`, and then maybe updating the age every 1000 milliseconds by taking the current time and subtracting the start time, but are there better solutions?

Comment: that sounds like a plan. but why update the age with a thread when it can be calculated whenever it's needed?  make a getAge() method which calls System.currentTimeMillis() and calculates the age offset from start time.

Comment: My advice is to implement it as you suggest (I presume you haven't yet). You will learn more when you actually encounter any shortcomings in your approach and have to overcome them or start from scratch. Simply asking which is a better way is cheating yourself of some experience.

Comment: Does this really need its own thread?  Storing the start-time, and calculating the difference from *now* is usually enough for most applications.

Comment: I would use `LocalTime` and one of the many [minus methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#minus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) to calculate the difference between now and when the egg was laid. I would then head over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and ask how I could improve.